# Set current slide for jQuery slider on page load Easy Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I am using the jQuery slider [Easy Slider](http://cssglobe.com/post/5780/easy-slider-17-numeric-navigation-jquery-slider) with the slides as links to other pages. The other pages that are loaded also have the slider with the same slides, in the same order, with the same links.

I cannot figure out how to set the current slide when a page loads.

For example: There are four slides. When slide three is clicked and the page loaded, I want the slider to be on slide three. It is frustrating to follow a link, and then have to navigate back through the previous slides.

I originally was loading the additional pages from the slide links with AJAX, but there is another jQuery script that is called when the additional pages are loaded and the $(document).ready function wouldn't get called.

I have not modified anything in the Easy Slider script, and am using it with default options. Here is the example code from Easy Slider for the slides.

```
<!-- markup example for $("#slider").easySlider(); -->
<div id="slider">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="someLink1"><img src="images/01.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="someLink2"><img src="images/02.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="someLink3"><img src="images/03.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="someLink4"><img src="images/04.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I would think it should be possible to add an id to the li tags and somehow modify the JS to reference that... Just not sure where to start.

Any help and direction would be stellar!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about that plugin specifically, but I could suggest you use the AnythingSlider - http://css-tricks.com/anythingslider-jquery-plugin/ - which will allow you to link to specific slides using hash-tags. So your links would be appended with something like #slide-4 - the plugin then sets that as the active one.

Comment: I'm going to check this out... I'll let you know.

Comment: In an effort to save time, I scratched debugging and went with AnythingSlider. The thing works great.

Answer (score 0):

You can call your old script though AJAX using the .live() function http://api.jquery.com/live/

or use server side(php) to change the order of the imgaes

Or jquery to find the element and remove with .detach() and then .append() to put it back at the top of the stack

hope this helps

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. I think on of the issues could be that I'm using Drupal, so there are some things that are a little screwy.

Comment: as long as the JS is right it would not mater what it was made produced by. Drupal will handle the back end not the browser side, if the last one is not working I would revisit the Jquery call.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this with the slider, but the logic for it should work (using the jQuery cookie plugin):

```
// check if a cookie is stored
if( $.cookie('pageId') != null ){
    // change the order of the li elements according to cookie ID stored
    $('#slider ul li:lt('+$.cookie('pageId')+')').appendTo($("#slider ul"));
}

// initiate slider
$("#slider").easySlider();   

// handle click events
$('#slider a').click(function(e){
    // prevent the click from going through 
    e.preventDefault();
    // store cookie with clicked item index
    $.cookie("pageId",$('#slider a').index(this));
    // forward the user onwards to the link url
    window.location = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

Comment: I REALLY like where you are headed with this one... But it didn't work. I made sure to download and include the cookie plugin. Any idea?

Comment: @danstever Was there any JavaScript errors? Did anything happen? Do you have a link to preview it somewhere?

Comment: I should as, should there have been any additional info added to the html? I left that all as is.

Comment: @danstever should probably work as is. Could you upload your page for preview so I could have a look at the problem myself?